# Is this power series expansion of $2{({\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}})^M}{K_M}({2\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}})$ correct?

Tags: power-series, special-functions, approximation

I am calculating the power series approximation of $f\left( x \right)$ at $x = \infty$.

With my
$f\left( x \right) = 2{\left( {\sqrt {\frac{1}{x}} } \right)^M}{K_M}\left( {2\sqrt {\frac{1}{x}} } \right)$

Where ${K_M}\left( x \right)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order $M$ (cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E9). In my application, M is a positive integer.

However, the received answer seem to be strange and I do not know if it **correct** or not ?

[image]

Because for any positive integer $M$ then $\Gamma \left( { - M} \right)$ would result in a Complex Infinity.

However, when I plug in the actual value $M=2,4$. I receive a neat approximation that suit my application. Therefore, I hope to be able to derive a generalized answer like this for any $M$ (even or odd).

[image]

Please help me with this !

Thank you !

Comment: Looks like your CAS simply doesn't "understand" that $M$ is an *integer*.

Comment: @metamorphy. Even if precised in the assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the output line, it starts with $x^{\color{red}{-}M}$ so, who cares since $M>0$ and $x\to \infty$.

So, just use
$$\Gamma (M)\left(1-\frac{1}{(M-1) x}+\frac{1}{2 (M-2) (M-1)
   x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)$$

**Edit**

The case $M=1$ is totally different. The result should be
$$1-\frac{\log (x)-2 \gamma +1}{x}-\frac{2 \log (x)-4 \gamma +5}{4 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

Comment: Oh where does $\frac{1}{{2\left( {M - 2} \right)\left( {M - 1} \right){x^2}}}$ come from ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh. I made the expansion to second order.

Comment: Thank you, then is there anyway to deal with the case $M=1$

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh. Have a look at my edit

Comment: Thank you so so much !